# S3 deny access to administrators

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

For one AWS S3 bucket, I would like to deny access to everyone except for one specific IAM role.  I created a role-based policy to allow access and that works.  But other IAM users are also able to access objects and I want to prevent this.  I tried adding a bucket policy like this, which denies everyone except this principal and then allows this principal.  But this policy blocks access to everyone including that role.

The other IAM users I am trying to block are attached to the built-in AdminstratorAccess policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "PolicySecretBucket",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "StmtDenyAll",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::********:role/service-role/my-role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "StmtAllowLambdaBot",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::********:role/service-role/my-role"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Role ARNs are typically `arn:aws:iam::********:role/my-role` but please test `arn:aws:sts::**********:assumed-role/myrole/mysession` where the session name is `mysession`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is how I would do it:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::MyExampleBucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::MyExampleBucket/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotLike": {
          "aws:userId": [
            "AROAEXAMPLEID:*",
            "ACCOUNT NUMBER"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

this is how it works.

- the user's will have an IAM policy which allows `s3.*` actions
- we will deny all the s3 actions for the bucket `MyExampleBucket` for any user id but the user id of the role (and the user id of the root account in case if the role is deleted) using the bucket policy

to get the user id of the role:

```
aws iam get-role --role-name ROLE-NAME
```

And finally, why yours does not work: https://serverfault.com/a/988136

reference:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-restrict-amazon-s3-bucket-access-to-a-specific-iam-role/

Comment: And please accept the answer if its working for you, so that I can confirm my understanding

Comment: This works great, thank you!  In this case I'm using this bucket to store API credentials, so I restricted access only to GetObject.  I want myself and other admins to be able to put new objects, but only the designated Lambda functions can read them.

Answer (score 1):

Denying access to a specific bucket is **actually quite difficult**.

For example, an Administrator might have permissions to **assume the Role**, so they can still access the bucket.

You would also need to review all policies to ensure that only authorized people can use `iam:PassRole` to **assume the role via an Amazon EC2 instance**.

An safer approach would be to **put the bucket in a separate AWS Account**. Then, only give cross-account access to specific users (not a Role). This way, the default is that Admins have zero access and you then grant access to the desired people. There are less ways to "get around" this type of access.

Comment: Thanks for your insight.  In this case I don't mind if admins can assume the role because we trust each other not to do something bad.  I just want to prevent accidental easy access.  But actually, since I'm using Lambda service roles, I don't think it's possible to assume these.